# How to connect the teradata connection details in python

Tags: python-3.x, teradata, cx-oracle

I am trying to connect to Teradata using cx_Oracle  in Python.

import cx_Oracle
import psycopg2

connection = 'user/hostname/password'
con = cx_Oracle.connect(connection)

getting the error: net service name is incorrectly specified

Answer (score 0):

Teradata has its own driver, *cx_Oracle* is used to connect to Oracle databases. I think (I'm not sure, I don't have experience with Teradata databases, but this is what [Teradata documentation](https://docs.teradata.com/r/Teradata-Tools-and-Utilities-Release-Definition/October-2018/Product-Information/Teradata-SQL-Driver-for-Python) states) that the driver you need is teradatasql: `pip install teradatasql`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I connect to Teradata with Python

```
import sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine

engine_str = (f"teradatasql://{username}:{password}@{host}/")
pd.read_sql_query(query, engine_str)
```

sqlalchemy does, however, require you to have the teradata dialect installed as well.

```
pip install teradatasqlalchemy
```